# need a hand with that like system

Tags: php

here's the full code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION["sess_user"])){
        header("location:../logout.php");
    } else {}
    $user=$_SESSION['sess_user'];
    ?>

<?php
    $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','vertrigo') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die("cannot select DB");
    $sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `likehand`");
    while($likehandle = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
            {

                $fanname = $likehandle['Userlame']; 
                $Posid = $likehandle['Post_ID'];    

    }
    ?>

            <?php
                            echo "<div style='background-color: #CC98CC'>";
                echo "<tr align='center'bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>";    
                echo"<td><p align='center'><font size='1' color='black'><b>Welcome Back $user </b></a></font></p></td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "</div>";

            echo"<p align='center'><i><b>
<font style='opacity: 100' size='7' color='000000' face='forte'>News</font></b></i></p>";


            include("newsdb.php");

                if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                if(!empty($_POST['search'])) {
                $srhuser=$_POST['search'];

$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','vertrigo') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_registration') or die("cannot select DB");
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news` where submitted_by='".$srhuser."'");}}
else{$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `news`\n"
    . " ORDER BY `code` DESC");

}

            while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {

                $sbmitter = $test['submitted_by'];
                $id = $test['code'];    
                $date = $test['date'];
                $body = $test['body'];
                $likes = $test['likes'];
                $image = $test['url'];
                $sql="SELECT * FROM `likehand`";

                echo "<div style='background-color: #C0C0C0'>";
                echo "<tr align='center'bgcolor='#f0f0f0'>";    
                echo"<td><i><left><font color='black'>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; $sbmitter Said:</center></font></i>";
                echo"<td><p align='center'><font size='4' color='black'>$body</a></font></p></td>";
                echo"<font color='Black'><p align='right'>created <a href='#'>";echo"<font color='blue'>";
                echo date('d-m-Y \a\t\ g:i <b>a</b></a>', strtotime($test["date"]));                  // October 5, 2008 9:34 pm
echo"&nbsp";
$userid="$user-$id";
                if("$fanname-$Posid" == $userid){echo"<td><p align='Left'><font size='2' color='black'>&nbsp&nbsp$likes like <a href ='unlike.php?code=$id'><font color='black'><input type='button' value='Unlike' name='B3' style='width: 50; height: 20'></a></a></font></p></td>";


}else{    echo"<td><p align='Left'><font size='2' color='black'>&nbsp&nbsp$likes like <a href ='like.php?code=$id'><font color='black'><input type='button' value='like' name='B3' style='width: 50; height: 20'></a></a></font></p></td>";
                }               if($sbmitter == $user)
{               echo"<td><p align='right'><font size='2' color='black'><a href ='adminpannel/postdel.php?code=$id'><font color='black'><input type='button' value='delete' name='B3' style='width: 50; height: 20'></a></a></font></td>";
                echo"<td><font size='2' color='black'><a href ='/adminpannel/postedit.php?code=$id'><font color='black'><input type='button' value='edit' name='B3' style='width: 50; height: 20'></a></a></font></p></td>";
}
}


                echo "</div>";
                echo "<p></p>";
                echo"&nbsp;";



                echo "</tr>";

            mysql_close($conn);
            ?>
```

i think the problem is here, but dunno what is it:

```
        $userid="$user-$id";
            if("$fanname-$Posid" == $userid){echo"<td><p align='Left'><font size='2' color='black'>&nbsp&nbsp$likes like <a href ='unlike.php?code=$id'><font color='black'><input type='button' value='Unlike' name='B3' style='width: 50; height: 20'></a></a></font></p></td>";


}else{    echo"<td><p align='Left'><font size='2' color='black'>&nbsp&nbsp$likes like <a href ='like.php?code=$id'><font color='black'><input type='button' value='like' name='B3' style='width: 50; height: 20'></a></a></font></p></td>";
                }
```

i re-checked the database and it appears that it saves the data correctly, the problem is when user press like.. likes field increases by one and post id as well as user name are saved, but when i like more than one post, only one post show the "unlike" button..
any suggestions ?

Comment: please introduce the problem before posting the code.  This will make the question easier to understand for readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is really painful to look at. Also so many things you should've done differently. To start with you should avoid mysql functions, they are deprecated. Use mysqli, or pdo. If you go for mysqli, make sure to take the object oriented version. I'm not sure if the 'full code' is 2 separate scripts... if it isn't, then why do you make connection to mysql AND the database twice? Also weird way of checking certain things in if-statements.

The reason why you only see 1 like at a time is because at the start, you take all the likes out of the database, and then do a while loop. Then you put the information in $fanname and $posid. Every like will update these values. So in the end, only the information of ONE like will be stored.

Simple fix, as of now, would be to replace this:

```
$fanname = $likehandle['Userlame'];
$posid = $likehandle['Post_ID'];
```

with

```
$array_of_likes[$fanname . "-" . $posid] = 1;
```

Then replace this:

```
if("$fanname-$Posid" == $userid){
```

with

```
if(array_key_exists($userid, $array_of_likes)){
```

This should at least allow you to like more than 1 thing.

Edit:
Some more advice towards your script:
It seems you select all likes, from every user. I believe that's not really what you want. You do want to do WHERE userlame = {your_user_ID} in the query.

When you do this, then change the array of likes. You don't need to create a key with fanname and posid. Just create a array with post_id as key.

Then when you check if you have liked the news post, do array_key_exists($id, $array_of_likes). No need to send your username in it.

But a much better approach would be using a LEFT JOIN query on the news-query.
Something like this:

```
SELECT n.*, l.POST_ID FROM news AS n
    LEFT JOIN likehand AS l
    ON l.userlame = $your_user_id AND l.Post_ID = n.code
WHERE n.submittedby = $_POST['search']
```

I cannot beautify the query, but it's about that.
It selects all the news-messages from the guy that you search for. At the same time it checks if there's a like from you, matching the post. If you have liked it, then l.POST_ID is a number. If you haven't liked it, l.POST_ID is a null.

Comment: i know the code is way too messy, but it ain't the way i use, i make a test php file to mess out then clean, thanks for the answer, gonna try it

Comment: worked, thanks alot.

Comment: @Abdel-MoniemMoragy I've updated my post a little. More advice towards a better script. Even a faster script, if you apply the query. But you might have to do some researching to get it fully going.